# For com if não funciona

Tags: vba, excel-vba

O código precisa testar uma lista com duas frases. Se ele encontrar essa frase, ele a copia e cola na célula a esquerda ela, até que ele encontre a próxima frase. Tudo funciona bem no primeiro For (For i), mas já no segundo (For j) parece não funcionar mais.

[image: base do excel]

```
Sub o()

For i = 1 To 30
If Cells(i, 2) = "01 dormitório" Then Exit For
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i

Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select

For j = 1 To 30
If Cells(j, 2) = "02 Dormitórios" Then Exit For

ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next j

Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Na descrição está "e cola na célula anterior a ela" (anterior é a imediatamente de cima?), mas na tela de exemplo, está fixo na "A1" (COLA AQUI A FRASE...). Qual é o esperado? Se for na "A1", o "01 dormitório" vai ser sobreposto pelo "02 Dormitório", por exemplo.

Comment: Descrevi errado. É "cola na celula a esquerda"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O código original tem alguns problemas, vou reformular e explicar alguns pontos.

**Exemplo 01** - Seguindo a lógica original de um `For` para cada frase teste:

```
Sub testeFraseExemplo1()

Dim linha As Integer 'declara a linha como inteiro

For linha = 1 To 30 'verificará da linha 1 até a 30
    If Cells(linha, 2) = "01 dormitório" Then 'verifica se é o texto esperado
        Cells(linha, 2).Copy Cells(linha, 1) 'copia a célula da linha do for coluna B, para a célula mesma linha coluna A
        Exit For 'encerra o for, pois já encontrou
    End If 'fecha if
Next linha 'próxima linha, se não foi encerrado no if verdadeiro

For linha = 1 To 30
    If Cells(linha, 2) = "02 Dormitórios" Then
        Cells(linha, 2).Copy Cells(linha, 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next linha

End Sub
```

Repare que não precisa utilizar outro nome para linha (como fez com i e j). Pode reaproveitar ela, o `For` redefine para `1 To 30` (ou outro range que definir ao declarar ele). O restante do código é idêntico ao bloco superior, mudando a frase somente.

**Exemplo 02** - É possível utilizar o mesmo `For`, com mais de um `If`. Ainda, é possível utilizar o mesmo `If` com mais de uma condição (frase teste).

```
Sub testeFraseTipoExemplo2()

Dim linha As Integer

For linha = 1 To 30
    If Cells(linha, 2) = "01 dormitório" Or _
        Cells(linha, 2) = "02 Dormitórios" Then 'pode ir acrescentando outros Or ou And
        Cells(linha, 2).Copy Cells(linha, 1)
    End If
Next linha

End Sub
```

Escolher um ou outro depende do projeto final, está relacionado a manutenção, performance de ter vários For analisando as mesmas linhas e etc. Tendo a indicar a segunda opção, mas tudo depende.

Comment: Muito bom. Ha algum jeito para que a cada linha testada ele cole na celula de baixo a palavra copiada?

Comment: Sim, é possível, mas é provável que te cause erros. Imagina que na linha 06 tenha "01 dormitório" e na linha 07 "02 Dormitórios", então quando o For ler a linha 06 ele vai copiar e vai sobrescrever o conteúdo atual da linha 07 por "copiada". Agora, ao ler a linha 07 não terá mais "02 Dormitórios". Não parece fazer sentido implementar essa regra, mas o código seria após a linha que copia: Cells(linha+1, 2) = "copiada".

Comment: Muito obrigado jean. Resolveu tudo. So mais uma coisa. Quantos anos para ter esse conhecimento?

Comment: Não diria que é questão de anos... Mas resiliência e dedicação. Sempre temos o que aprender (sem filosofia, na real mesmo). Boa sorte nos estudos.